# Служив отлично благородно, Долгами жил его отец

Tags: морфология

Почему в романе Пушкина используется деепричастие совершенного вида "служив"?

Оно относится к глаголу несовершенного вида "жил" и обозначает одновременное с ним действие. Тогда, как мне кажется,  это должно быть деепричастие несовершенного вида "служа", образованное от глагола несовершенного вида "служить"

У Зализняка я нашла только деепричастие "служа", но в других словарях встречаются оба варианта.

Поэтому возникают такие вопросы:

Существуют оба деепричастия (служа и служив)?

Почему у Пушкина используется деепричастие "служив", разве это верно по смыслу?

Примечание

Запятая между "отлично благородно" не ставится?

Позже я нашла в Интернете информацию на эту тему, но не знаю, насколько ей можно доверять http://netler.ru/slovari/otlichno-blagorodno.htm

"Слово отлично-благородно пишется через дефис (в первых изданиях романа «Евгений Онегин» было напечатано раздельно – «отлично благородно». В 1937 г., при издании полного собрания сочинений А.С. Пушкина, слова были объединены дефисом)".

Но реально встречаются три формы: нет знака, запятая, дефис. Конечно, отсутствие знака кажется странным, ведь это однородные наречия со сходным значением. Если это действительно авторский вариант, то нужно ли его исправлять по современным правилам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Частичный ответ.

**Запятая между "отлично благородно" не ставится?**

Не ставится, хотя в старых изданиях почти всюду есть запятая (об этом писал М. Горький в 1931 г.). Другие комментаторы отмечают, что варианты с запятой были изданы или подготовлены ещё при жизни поэта. В черновиках Пушкина тоже стояла запятая, но некоторые комментаторы считают её ошибочной. В известных мне добротных современных изданиях "отлично-благородно" написано через дефис (в таких вопросах лучше смотреть хорошие бумажные издания, а не "пересказы" в сети).

[Здесь ссылка на наиболее полное и интересное](http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=RAdHQ-HLowM%3D&tabid=11119), что удалось найти из комментариев (см. стр. 60-62).

По поводу канцелярита уже ответили, но я хотел бы отметить, что к канцеляриту, вероятно, относится только выражение "отлично-благородно", а не деепричастие "служив", о котором Вы спрашиваете. Это становится понятно из тех же комментариев по ссылке выше. По поводу слова "служив" у меня нет уверенного ответа — здесь нужен более аккуратный комментарий специалиста, знающего язык тех времён.

Answer (score 2):

Нашла парочку наводок - из ну очень сурьёзной литературы, однако картинка нумер два недоотображена, по ней только в "угадайку" сыграть можно...

Рассуждения литературоведа [Константина Азадовского](https://books.google.ru/books?id=o0EwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT171&dq=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijqv6I8aneAhXFiiwKHR6KDSMQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Гугл-Книги), читабельные и внятные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чьи изыскания - невемо, но тоже [кого-то очень-очень продвинутого](https://books.google.ru/books?id=_TQLAQAAMAAJ&q=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&dq=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijqv6I8aneAhXFiiwKHR6KDSMQ6AEIRjAF):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Набираю своей рукой: "Впрочем, и на этот раз текст Пушкина наталкивал на ошибку, поскольку он и сам требовал комментария", - зеро...

---

Что касаемо *служив - служа:* сказано ж: формула, идиома такая, пересмотру не подлежит!

> Служив отлично-благородно… — Официальная формула бюрократического
>   языка, употреблявшаяся при аттестации чиновников, означает: "весьма
>   благородно", "заслуживающим отличия образом".
>   [Ю.М. Лотман. Комментарий к "Евгению Онегину"](http://vivovoco.astronet.ru/VV/PAPERS/LOTMAN/ONEGIN/CHAPT01/INDEX.HTM)
>
> ---

Всё, разобрались!

***В формуле дефис был! Пушкин сострил, убрав его!***

Comment: Спасибо, всё очень интересно, но ясности до конца нет.  В современном языке варианты с запятой или дефисом означает однородные понятия, а вариант без знаков - неоднородные, то есть наречие + наречие (интересное,  нестандартное прочтение). Что касается того времени, то там правила  могли быть другими, тогда отлично-благородно могло означать "весьма (отличительно) благородно", как и в современном тексте без знака.  Сейчас этот  вопрос важен для выбора прочтения: при постановке запятой должно быть перечисление, при дефисе - чтение в одно слово, без знака - голосом подчеркиваем только благородно.

Comment: Что касается основного вопроса "служа или служив", то он к формуле, как мне кажется, не относится. В современном языке программа подчеркивает "служив" как неправильное написание, а в то время этот вариант мог употребляться.

Comment: 2. Лотману не верите?! О_о 1. Азадовскому не верите?! О_о А какую мы ищем ясность? Пушкин убрал знак - быть посему.

Comment: Честно говоря, я спрашивала про служа-служив, а на отсутствие запятой случайно обратила внимание. Но в принципе любой школьник может спросить: почему нет запятой?.Так было у Пушкина? А почему Пушкин не поставил запятую (случайно или намеренно, с глубоким смыслом)? Другой актуальный для современного читателя вопрос: как это читается? Скорее всего, читают с перечислением, как будто запятая есть.  Но ведь мы не читаем "весьма благородно"  с перечислением, когда первое наречие подчинено другому. Значит ли это, что мы неправильно читаем Пушкина?

Comment: Но у Азадовского же все ответы на Ваши вопросы - см. цитату.

Comment: Да, это как раз то, на что интересно обратить внимание. Но вряд ли там говорится о том, как читается текст без запятой. И вряд ли обычный читатель понимает смысл  текста без запятой.

Answer (score 1):

"Служив отлично благородно" - официальная формула-характеристика при аттестации чиновника государственной службы.
http://www.poetry-classic.ru/1-3.html

Собственно, вот и ответ на оба вопроса.

Comment: Зря кто-то поставил минус, ведь находка интересная. Правда вопросы остаются... Кто автор примечаний, можно ли ему доверять? Эта "официальная формула-характеристика" употреблялась именно с деепричастием *служив*? Почему все-таки не *служа*?  Так было принято? А как правильно в наше время?

Comment: @М_Г Минус поставил я. И я считаю, что зря кто-то поставил плюс за такой поверхностный ответ на хороший вопрос по Пушкину. Вы в своём комментарии верно указали на некоторые проблемы этого ответа. Я не вижу ничего хорошего в стремлении дать на любой вопрос максимально быстрый и короткий ответ, не затратив на него никаких усилий.

Comment: @grizzly Плюс тоже зря поставили, ответ недоработан.

Comment: Я хотел как-то "вдохновить" автора ответа на доработку...

Comment: @М_Г Я уточню для ясности основную причину минуса. Утверждение Niemand, что "отлично благородно" пишется без дефиса, основано на информации с какой-то Интернет-мусорки. Я даже не могу проверить (и не я должен проверять!), существовало ли когда-нибудь такое издание на бумаге, были ли у него редактор и корректор. Или, может, решение о раздельном написании принял дизайнер-верстальщик, а то и просто система автоматической проверки грамотности.

Comment: *Утверждение Niemand, что "отлично благородно" пишется без дефиса...* Утверждение - в студию. *Или, может, решение о раздельном написании принял дизайнер-верстальщик* Может. А может, и нет. Проведем исследование? У меня образования не хватит, боюсь, что у @grizzly тоже. *...даже не могу проверить (и не я должен проверять!)* - А кто должен?

Comment: А Вы собственный ответ прочитать не могли бы? И разве не очевидно, что автор ответа несёт ответственность за правильность и достоверность информации в нём? (Впрочем, автор может вести себя безответственно, но другие участники должны оценивать это по достоинству.)

Comment: Если бы я был специалистом - я бы мог нести *полную ответственность*. Но я, в отличие от очень многих здесь, специалиста из себя не строю. Я всего лишь неплохо знаю язык. Поэтому длинных, обстоятельных, наукообразных ответов стараюсь избегать, ибо это смешно. Специалистов здесь, за исключением *Людмилы* и *Галины Аванесовой*, нет вообще. Верно? А посему - только лишь личное мнение или мнения, найденные в сети, которые показались заслуживающими внимания.